# C++: System call for restarting ntpd -> wrong port

Tags: c++, port, ntp, ntpd

currently I am writing my master thesis and got a little problem in C++. Under certain conditions, I have to restart the ntp daemon, therefore I call:

```
system("service ntp restart");
```

But after this ntp is not listening on port 123, but rather 8377 and 8378. This port belong to an udp channel, which is used in the C++-prog.

Does anyone got an idea for this malicious behaviour ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What happens if you run the command from the shell?

Comment: Then it will listen on port 123 and everything is fine!

Comment: Doesn't this restart require superuser privilege ?

Comment: Sure, the program will be run as root ;-) This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The system() executes shell command and result of this shell command has nothing common with C++. You problem is definitely not with the C++ but with the shell script:

```
service ntp restart
```

Please verify the results of that command and check the command envrionment since there is a big chance that you need to set environment variables. But all this - shell issues, not C++ ones.

Comment: Hot to set environment variables, when the program is called with sudo and the system call referes the shell? (yeah, i am not really confident with linux)

Comment: env <VARIABLE_0>=<VALUE_0> .. <VARIABLE_N>=<VALUE_N> <SHELL COMMAND> <ARG_0> .. <ARG_N>

Comment: Sorry, but I've already said that I'm not confident with linux. Which parameters are to set?

Comment: This is particular for your system. To get the basic idea about that - type man bash and check the /etc/init.d/ntp. As alternative - please consult to your system administrator since the questions you are asking is not a C++ questions but it is general SA questions. I even have no idea about flavour of Linux you are using. I can count 40 flavors from scratch :)

Comment: I'll have a look, and by the way: it' Ubuntu with Unity, but I'll change for something more "basic", maybe Xubuntu with Enlightment as windows manager :) Thx